# CFDEM compilation in stl and stl_map

Tags: c++, stl

I have a problem in compiling CFDEM package (I don't know if somebody knows), however normally it compiles without any problem, but when I switch on an option, it gives me this error,

```
/cm/shared/apps/gcc/4.7.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.0/../../../../include/c++/4.7.0/bits/stl_map.h:113:2: error: declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]
/cm/shared/apps/gcc/4.7.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.0/../../../../include/c++/4.7.0/bits/stl_map.h: In constructor âstd::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::value_compare::value_compare(_Compare)â:
/cm/shared/apps/gcc/4.7.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.0/../../../../include/c++/4.7.0/bits/stl_map.h:116:8: error: anachronistic old-style base class initializer [-fpermissive]
In file included from /cm/shared/apps/gcc/4.7.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.0/../../../../include/c++/4.7.0/map:62:0,
             from /users/maione1/LIGGGHTS/LIGGGHTS-PUBLIC/src/input.h:29,
             from /users/maione1/LIGGGHTS/LIGGGHTS-PUBLIC/src/fix_property_global.h:33,
             from /users/maione1/LIGGGHTS/LIGGGHTS-PUBLIC/src/property_registry.h:32,
             from /users/maione1/LIGGGHTS/LIGGGHTS-PUBLIC/src/force.h:28,
             from subModels/dataExchangeModel/twoWayMPI/twoWayMPI.H:49,
             from subModels/dataExchangeModel/twoWayMPI/twoWayMPI.C:33:
/cm/shared/apps/gcc/4.7.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.0/../../../../include/c++/4.7.0/bits/stl_multimap.h: At global scope:
/cm/shared/apps/gcc/4.7.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.0/../../../../include/c++/4.7.0/bits/stl_multimap.h:113:2: error: declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]
/cm/shared/apps/gcc/4.7.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.0/../../../../include/c++/4.7.0/bits/stl_multimap.h: In constructor âstd::multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::value_compare::value_compare(_Compare)â:
/cm/shared/apps/gcc/4.7.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.0/../../../../include/c++/4.7.0/bits/stl_multimap.h:116:8: error: anachronistic old-style base class initializer [-fpermissive]
In file included from subModels/dataExchangeModel/twoWayMPI/twoWayMPI.H:50:0,
             from subModels/dataExchangeModel/twoWayMPI/twoWayMPI.C:33:
lnInclude/forceModel.H: At global scope:
lnInclude/forceModel.H:155:36: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
subModels/dataExchangeModel/twoWayMPI/twoWayMPI.C: In constructor âFoam::twoWayMPI::twoWayMPI(const 
subModels/dataExchangeModel/twoWayMPI/twoWayMPI.C:75:19: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast]
subModels/dataExchangeModel/twoWayMPI/twoWayMPI.C:75:19: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast]
subModels/dataExchangeModel/twoWayMPI/twoWayMPI.C:76:19: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast]
subModels/dataExchangeModel/twoWayMPI/twoWayMPI.C:76:19: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast]
subModels/dataExchangeModel/twoWayMPI/twoWayMPI.C:81:20: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast]
subModels/dataExchangeModel/twoWayMPI/twoWayMPI.C:81:20: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast]
subModels/dataExchangeModel/twoWayMPI/twoWayMPI.C:98:20: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast]
subModels/dataExchangeModel/twoWayMPI/twoWayMPI.C:98:20: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast]
subModels/dataExchangeModel/twoWayMPI/twoWayMPI.C:98:30: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast]
subModels/dataExchangeModel/twoWayMPI/twoWayMPI.C:98:30: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast]
subModels/dataExchangeModel/twoWayMPI/twoWayMPI.C:100:38: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast]
subModels/dataExchangeModel/twoWayMPI/twoWayMPI.C:100:38: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast]
subModels/dataExchangeModel/twoWayMPI/twoWayMPI.C:100:49: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast]
subModels/dataExchangeModel/twoWayMPI/twoWayMPI.C:100:49: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast]
subModels/dataExchangeModel/twoWayMPI/twoWayMPI.C: In member function âvirtual void Foam::twoWayMPI::getData(Foam::word, Foam::word, double** const&, Foam::label) constâ:
subModels/dataExchangeModel/twoWayMPI/twoWayMPI.C:137:58: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast]
subModels/dataExchangeModel/twoWayMPI/twoWayMPI.C:137:72: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to âchar*â [-Wwrite-strings]
subModels/dataExchangeModel/twoWayMPI/twoWayMPI.C: In member function âvirtual void Foam::twoWayMPI::getData(Foam::word, Foam::word, int** const&, Foam::label) constâ:
subModels/dataExchangeModel/twoWayMPI/twoWayMPI.C:137:58: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast]
subModels/dataExchangeModel/twoWayMPI/twoWayMPI.C:137:72: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to âchar*â [-Wwrite-strings]
subModels/dataExchangeModel/twoWayMPI/twoWayMPI.C: In member function âvirtual void Foam::twoWayMPI::getData(Foam::word, Foam::word, int** const&, Foam::label) constâ:
subModels/dataExchangeModel/twoWayMPI/twoWayMPI.C:150:58: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast]
subModels/dataExchangeModel/twoWayMPI/twoWayMPI.C:150:69: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to âchar*â [-Wwrite-strings]
subModels/dataExchangeModel/twoWayMPI/twoWayMPI.C: In member function âvirtual void Foam::twoWayMPI::giveData(Foam::word, Foam::word, double** const&, const char*) constâ:
subModels/dataExchangeModel/twoWayMPI/twoWayMPI.C:164:57: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast]
subModels/dataExchangeModel/twoWayMPI/twoWayMPI.C: In member function âvirtual bool Foam::twoWayMPI::couple() constâ:
subModels/dataExchangeModel/twoWayMPI/twoWayMPI.C:275:20: warning: unused variable âinterruptTimeâ [-Wunused-variable]
make: *** [Make/linux64GccDPOpt/twoWayMPI.o] Error 1
```

thanks for your help,

Riccardo Maione

Comment: "but when I switch on an option" you have mention what is that option.

Comment: it is the comp option, for compressible fluid treatment it should only change how some component are calculated and files to be called, but as of now the compiler give error in different places

Comment: the file giving problem is twoWayMpi.H [link](https://github.com/CFDEMproject/CFDEMcoupling-PUBLIC/blob/master/src/lagrangian/cfdemParticle/subModels/dataExchangeModel/twoWayMPI/twoWayMPI.C), I tried to compile the programm without it, and it compiles, but it is a function I need, so if anyone no even the meaning of the error it would be highly appreciated thanks